# C++ program does nothing when executed

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks, stdvector

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 using the default c++ compiler it comes with. I am trying to get the size of vector required from the keyboard and eventually fill a vector with the increasing value of i in the makeGaps function. I would then like to return a filled vector to my variable x. However, when I run the code below, after it displays the "enter gap size" it does nothing even after I supply an integer.   No output, no errors and also in code blocks all the debugger icons go gray. The code also doesn't 
terminate and I cannot figure out what is wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 using namespace std;

 vector<int> makeGaps (int size){
    vector<int>  vectorOfGaps(size);
    for(int i = 0; i <= vectorOfGaps.size();i++){
        vectorOfGaps.push_back(i);
    }
    return vectorOfGaps;
}
void printV(vector<int> collection){
    for (int i = 0; i <= collection.size(); i++){
        cout << collection[i]<< '\n';
    }
}
int main()
{   //get the number of gaps required
    int numberOfGaps;
    cout << "Enter gap size";
    cin >> numberOfGaps;
    vector<int> x = makeGaps(numberOfGaps);
    printV(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Also if i run it in the terminal that comes with vs code it crashes my machine.

Comment: Did you try providing an input? Seems like it's blocking at the `cin` which waits for user input.

Comment: And after providing the input, the function call that prints anything is commented out. What exactly did you expect this program to do?

Comment: yes I did I entered 10 but nothing happens no matter how many times I type a digit

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i <= collection.size();i++)` means `i` will always eventually be `collection.size()` which is not a valid index. The valid indices of an `std::vector`, like for arrays, is `0` to `size - 1`. You'll eventually have the same problem in `makeGaps` when you fix the other errors there.

Comment: `vectorOfGaps.push_back(i)` will continually increase the size of your vector every iteration, so your `for` loop won't end. `i` and the size of your vector both increase by 1 every iteration. Use `vectorOfGaps[i] = i;` instead to assign to the elements that are already there.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I accidentally posted a version where I commented out printV for debugging purposes. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectors in c++ are dynamically sized.

You can create a vector without a size argument in the constructor then push size number of elements like so:

```
vector<int> makeGaps (int size){
    vector<int>  vectorOfGaps;
    for(int i = 0; i < size;i++){
        vectorOfGaps.push_back(i);
    }
    return vectorOfGaps;
}
```

Edit: Also, as someone already pointed out in your comments, it appears you had an off by one error in your for loop. If the for loop runs until `x <= size`, it will iterate `size+1` number of times.